# css align content in middle

Tags: html, css

what is the easiest way of making my webpage looking the same from mobile and desktop?
what i mean that when i open it from mobile i want to see the content on full width, and when i open it from desktop i want to see the same content, just not full width, but be in the middle of the page and have margins in both sides. like in the picture - on the left you can see the mobile version, with A being the content, on the right you can see the desktop version, with A being the same content, and the red box being a container or something and to the sides there's nothing.

http://s22.postimg.org/jn9rpa7f5/mob.jpg

Comment: Your question is way too general.  Start with media queries.  And, along the way take a look at viewport units and feature detection libraries such as Modernizr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- content -->
</div>

.wrapper{
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`margin: 0 auto` defines 0 margin for the top and bottom and `auto` for left and right, which will centre it. You can define your own width on the wrapper if you like.

Comment: also include media query for explicit targeting = @media (min-width: 700px) { ... }

Comment: thanks!
but what i meant was that i want the width of the content to be 320px, so when displayed on mobile it will take the whole width, but when on desktop it will have big white margins...

Comment: ohh great thanks! i also just noticed your comment there, thanks again!